# How do I get the value property in this CosmosDb Query?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to get deeper into an object but for some reason it does not work in my Cosmos query, the query is quite simple as follows.

```
SELECT c.id,  
c.ItemNo, 
bv.variantId AS variantNo, 
bv.variantDescription AS title, 
c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription[0] AS Description,
c.BasicData.presentation.articleCompositionList.origin,
bv.size.sizeName,
c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path
FROM c
JOIN bv IN c.BasicData.base.sales.variants
WHERE c.brand = 'XXX'
AND c.Consumer = 'XXX'
AND bv.variantId = 'XXX'
AND c.Season = 'XXX'
```

The result is rather straight forward too as follows

```
[
    {
        "id": "9c9c5b56-999f-4f98-8c52-902f43dd4cfe",
        "ItemNo": "0562168014",
        "variantNo": "0562168014003",
        "title": "Trousers Grey, 36",
        "Description": {
            "locale": "en-GB",
            "value": "jongel fibbel"
        },
        "origin": "{\"\":{\"materials\":{\"002elastane\":\"30.0\",\"002polyester\":\"70.0\"}}}",
        "path": "https://public.assets.XXX.com/assets/002/b0/1b/b01b4fa77023f48ca3c6ff8777cc27276f478f1e.jpg"
    }
]
```

My problem is I want to return the "value" property "jongel fibbel" instead of the entire description object

I tried changing

```
c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription[0] AS Description,
```

To

```
c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription[0].value AS Description,
```

But that gives me a syntax error at value

How can I return the value properly in the above query?

EDIT -------

```
aricleLongDescription is an array as follows

"articleLongDescription": [
                {
                    "locale": "en-GB",
                    "value": "jongel fibbel"
                }
            ],
```

SO I also tried JOIN as follows

```
SELECT c.id,  
c.ItemNo, 
bv.variantId AS variantNo, 
bv.variantDescription AS title, 
ba.value AS Description,
c.BasicData.presentation.articleCompositionList.origin,
bv.size.sizeName,
c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path
FROM c
JOIN bv IN c.BasicData.base.sales.variants
JOIN ba IN c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription
WHERE c.brand = 'XXX'
AND c.Consumer = 'XXX'
AND bv.variantId = 'XXX'
AND c.Season = 'XXXX'
```

But it also fails with syntax error at value

EDIT ---

Also tried a subquery as follows

```
SELECT c.id,  
c.ItemNo, 
bv.variantId AS variantNo, 
bv.variantDescription AS title, 
--c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription[0] AS Description,
-- ARRAY(SELECT serving.description FROM serving IN food.servings) AS servings
ARRAY(SELECT jongel.value FROM jongel IN c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription) AS Description

c.BasicData.presentation.articleCompositionList.origin,
bv.size.sizeName,
c.BasicData.asset.assets[0].locations[1].path
FROM c
JOIN bv IN c.BasicData.base.sales.variants
JOIN ba IN c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription
WHERE c.brand = 'XXX'
AND c.Consumer = 'XXX'
AND bv.variantId = 'XXX'
AND c.Season = 'XXX'
```

But it also fails with syntax error at value, I am wondering is "value" a protected keyword or something in CosmosDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out value is a reserved keyword in CosmosDB so the syntax to get around that is as follows

```
c.BasicData.presentation.articleLongDescription[0]["value"] AS Description,
```

Note there is no .(dot) just brackets and doublequotes